# Why should you use an external OpenGL loader function instead of GLAD's built in loader?

Tags: opengl, glfw, glad

I've been using GLAD with SFML for some time and I've been using GLAD's built-in function loader, `gladLoadGL` which worked just fine for me. Now I'm looking at GLFW and it's saying both in their guide and on the Khronos opengl wiki that you should be using `gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)` instead. Is there any particular reason for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any particular reason for it?

Using `gladLoadGL` in conjunction with for example GLFW is resulting in having two code parts in the same program which basically do the same thing, without having any benefit.

For example, look at [what GLFW does on Windows](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/84ec99bb01b1d1367239d349f97781fd8abaae3a/src/wgl_context.c#L417) (it is similar on the other platforms):

> ```
> _glfw.wgl.instance = LoadLibraryA("opengl32.dll");
> ```

It dynamically loads the GL library behind your back. And it provides an abstraction for querying OpenGL function pointers (the core ones, and extension ones, using both `wglGetProcAddress` and raw `GetProcAdress`).

The GL loader glad generates [does the same things](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad/blob/57a5e15b873d7c3fcaa374fe15f74793f84d3d15/glad/lang/c/loader/__init__.py#L35):

> ```
>     libGL = LoadLibraryW(L"opengl32.dll");
> ```

Now one might argue that loading the same shared library twice isn't a big deal, as this should result in re-using the same internal handles and is dealt by reference counting, but even so, it is just unnecessary code, and it still consumes memory and some time during initialization.

So unless you have some very specific reason for why you would need glad's code - maybe in a modified form to really do something else (like using a different GL library then the one which your system would use by default), there is no use case for this code - and it seems a reasonable recommendation to not include code which isn't needed.

As a side note: I often see projects using GLFW and GL loaders like GLAD or GLEW linking `opengl32.lib` or `libGL.so` at link time - this is absolutely unnecessary also, as the code will always load the libraries at runtime manually, and there should not be any GL symbols left at link time which the linker could resolve from the GL lib anyway.